# How to publish only one message on a topic?

Tags: ros, publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,

I have written a program which continuously publishes velocity on a topic. I want to publish only one velocity message at once. In case I change my velocity I need to publish one message per velocity change. How can I do it. Here is my code:

```
> #include "ros/ros.h"
> #include "nav_msgs/Odometry.h" 
> #include <ros/console.h>
> #include "geometry_msgs/Pose.h"
> #include "geometry_msgs/Twist.h"
> #include <tf/transform_datatypes.h>
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> double quatx; double quaty; double
> quatz; double quatw; double
> linearposx; double linearposy;
> 
> void ComPoseCallback(const
> nav_msgs::Odometry::ConstPtr& msg);
> 
> int main(int argc, char **argv) {
>     ros::init(argc, argv, "Test_FK"); 
>     ros::NodeHandle n;                 
>     ros::Publisher Velocity_pub = n.advertise<geometry_msgs::Twist>("/RosAria/cmd_vel",10);
>     ros::Subscriber ComPose_sub = n.subscribe("/RosAria/pose", 1000,
> ComPoseCallback);
> 
>        geometry_msgs::Twist velocity;    velocity.linear.x=1;   
> velocity.linear.y=0;   
> velocity.linear.z=0;   
> velocity.angular.x=0;   
> velocity.angular.y=0;   
> velocity.angular.z=0;
>         //std::cout<<"xPosition"<<linearposx<<std::endl;
> //ros::Rate loop_rate(10);
>        while (ros::ok())
>     {
>         Velocity_pub.publish(velocity);   
> ros::spinOnce();
>     
>    
>     }
>     return 0; }
> 
> void ComPoseCallback(const
> nav_msgs::Odometry::ConstPtr& msg)    
> {
>     ROS_INFO("Seq: [%d]", msg->header.seq);
>     ROS_INFO("Position-> x: [%f], y: [%f], z: [%f]",
> msg->pose.pose.position.x,msg->pose.pose.position.y,
> msg->pose.pose.position.z);
>     ROS_INFO("Orientation-> x: [%f], y: [%f], z: [%f], w: [%f]",
> msg->pose.pose.orientation.x,
> msg->pose.pose.orientation.y,
> msg->pose.pose.orientation.z,
> msg->pose.pose.orientation.w);
>         linearposx=msg->pose.pose.position.x; 
> linearposy=msg->pose.pose.position.y; 
> quatx= msg->pose.pose.orientation.x;  
> quaty= msg->pose.pose.orientation.y;  
> quatz= msg->pose.pose.orientation.z;  
> quatw= msg->pose.pose.orientation.w;
>        tf::Quaternion q(quatx, quaty, quatz, quatw);    tf::Matrix3x3 m(q); 
> double roll, pitch, yaw;   
> m.getEulerYPR(yaw, pitch, roll);
> //getRPY    ROS_INFO("Yaw: [%f],Pitch:
> [%f],Roll: [%f]",yaw,pitch,roll);
> 
>    return ; }
```

I am using pioneer 3dx robot which maintains its velocity once I give a velocity command. I don't need to send my velocity continuously.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/238470/how-to-publish-only-one-message-on-a-topic?/) by [Tomm](https://answers.ros.org/users/27284/tomm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 59 on 2016-06-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

First, please format your code properly, it is quite hard to read.

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "nav_msgs/Odometry.h" 
#include <ros/console.h>
#include "geometry_msgs/Pose.h"
#include "geometry_msgs/Twist.h"
#include <tf/transform_datatypes.h>

double quatx;
double quaty;
double quatz;
double quatw;
double linearposx;
double linearposy;

void ComPoseCallback(const nav_msgs::Odometry::ConstPtr& msg);

int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{
    ros::init(argc, argv, "Test_FK"); 
    ros::NodeHandle n;                 
    ros::Publisher Velocity_pub = n.advertise<geometry_msgs::Twist>("/RosAria/cmd_vel",10);
    ros::Subscriber ComPose_sub = n.subscribe("/RosAria/pose", 1000, ComPoseCallback);

    geometry_msgs::Twist velocity;
    velocity.linear.x=1;   
    velocity.linear.y=0;   
    velocity.linear.z=0;   
    velocity.angular.x=0;   
    velocity.angular.y=0;   
    velocity.angular.z=0;

    //std::cout<<"xPosition"<<linearposx<<std::endl;
    //ros::Rate loop_rate(10);

    while (ros::ok())
    {
        Velocity_pub.publish(velocity);   
        ros::spinOnce();
    }

 return 0;
 }

void ComPoseCallback(const nav_msgs::Odometry::ConstPtr& msg)    
{
    ROS_INFO("Seq: [%d]", msg->header.seq);
    ROS_INFO("Position-> x: [%f], y: [%f], z: [%f]",
        msg->pose.pose.position.x,msg->pose.pose.position.y,
        msg->pose.pose.position.z);
    ROS_INFO("Orientation-> x: [%f], y: [%f], z: [%f], w: [%f]",
        msg->pose.pose.orientation.x,
        msg->pose.pose.orientation.y,
        msg->pose.pose.orientation.z,
        msg->pose.pose.orientation.w);

    linearposx=msg->pose.pose.position.x; 
    linearposy=msg->pose.pose.position.y; 

    quatx= msg->pose.pose.orientation.x;  
    quaty= msg->pose.pose.orientation.y;  
    quatz= msg->pose.pose.orientation.z;  
    quatw= msg->pose.pose.orientation.w;

    tf::Quaternion q(quatx, quaty, quatz, quatw);
    tf::Matrix3x3 m(q); 

    double roll, pitch, yaw;   

    m.getEulerYPR(yaw, pitch, roll);

    //getRPY    ROS_INFO("Yaw: [%f],Pitch: [%f],Roll: [%f]",yaw,pitch,roll);

    return;
}
```

As far as I can tell, you don't change the velocity at all in this code. So why do you put the `Velocity_pub.publish(velocity)` within the while loop? Just publish it once before the loop and use 'ros::spin()' instead of 'ros::spinOnce()' to avoid the loop completely.

```
    Velocity_pub.publish(velocity); 
    ros::spin();
```

---

Originally posted by [JohnDoe2991](https://answers.ros.org/users/21163/johndoe2991/) with karma: 305 on 2016-06-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1